# Do CTEs (With statements) allow for common sub expression elimination in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I am writing a system that generates large SQL expressions and complex queries.
For my own sanity, I'm having the code generator use WITH expressions to simplify code and make it slightly more readable (an example of the horrors it still produces is here: https://pastebin.com/UZJ01Q19)

In some places, I want to reuse the result of a complex subexpression an arbitrary number times, and I was wondering how many times the bound expression is evaluated, in, for example

```
WITH ... AS <DoSetup>,
 intermediate AS <ComplexQuery>
SELECT a, b FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM intermediate WHERE ...)
    UNION
    (SELECT * FROM intermediate WHERE ...)
```

If `ComplexQuery` is evaluated twice in this expression, is there a way to rewrite the expression in a way that only evaluates it once? I've looked into creating temporary views, but that appears to re-evaluate the subquery on every access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a CTE, I'm pretty sure it does not re-execute the subquery every time the way it might when you use a view.  It should evaluate the query once and reference it multiple times.  If you run an explain plan, it will show you that the base tables are only accessed once.

[image]

I'm not an authority on the topic, and I trust if I'm reading this wrong that someone will correct me.

That aside, if your example above is a relevant one, you might be able to avoid doing a union against the CTE with a simple `OR` clause.  For example, if it looks like this:

```
select * from intermediate where a = 1 and b < 50
union
select * from intermediate where a >= 0 and c > 99
```

You could simply rewrite that as:

```
select *
from intermediate
where
  (a = 1 and b < 50) or
  (a >= 0 and c > 99)
```

Again, maybe your example was radically oversimplified, but I do see this a lot -- unions that would work better as an `or`.  Bear in mind that a `union` involves a sort, which is computationally expensive.

Comment: Thanks, my example with a union is indeed oversimplified - I just wanted to pick a simple way to reuse a query multiple times. However, it is something I'll bear in mind.